# Finding the 2,147,483,647th prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, computer-science

In computer science an array is indexed by an integer (`int`). Unlike in mathematics, the  computer science integer (`int`) has a finite range defined by the length of it's fixed binary representation.

In most modern higher level languages the maximum value of an integer is `2^31 - 1` (`2147483647`). I would like to create an array of **sequential** primes in a computer program I intend to write.

Example:

```
  list[0] =  2;
  list[1] =  3;
  list[2] =  5;  
  list[3] =  7;  
  list[4] = 11;  etc...
```

However, an array is indexed by an `int` so I can only have `2,147,483,647` entries in the array. Because of this I would like to know what the largest prime I could place in the array of sequential prime entries.

What value would be placed in `list[2147483647] = x;` What is the 2,147,483,647th prime number?

I'm not asking anyone in particular to calculate primes up to that iteration. I'm wondering how I might go about calculating it or find a place where it has already been precomputed. I know Wolfram has some precomputed primes but I couldn't find the correct prime tables.

**EDIT:**
I ask this question because I come from a computing background, not mathematics and I have difficulty estimating the size of the 2,147,483,647th prime number. Rather then the exact value, a rough value will suffice. I just need to know how roughly large this prime is.

1. If represented in binary, roughly how may bits would the 2,147,483,647th prime contain?
2. If represented in decimal, roughly how may digits would the 2,147,483,647th prime contain?

Comment: You can compute it in `Mathematica`, simply `Prime[2147483647]` yields `50685770143`. For some interesting subtleties concerning `Prime` I recommend reading this question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime

Comment: @awashburn:  yes, that prime is around 5.5E10, but Artes gave the exact value.  It has 11 decimal digits or 36 bits

Comment: @awashburn You can compute Prime[2147483647] in Wolfram|Alpha as well, since it relies on `Mathematica`.

Comment: @Artes Is Mathematica consulting a lookup table; or actually calculating the first N primes in order to return Prime[N]?

Comment: @DanNeely In http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#10453 you can find e.g. a note on Number Theoretic Functions, it says `Prime and PrimePi use sparse caching and sieving. For large n, the Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko algorithm for PrimePi is used, based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give Prime. `

Comment: I object to the notion that computer science integers necessarily have finite range. Programming integers tend to have finite range (although unlimited representations are standard in e.g. Python and Haskell), but computer science is not programming :)

Comment: @BenMillwood I have noted your fine distinction between computer science as an abstract study of computation and programming as a concrete implementation of computation, and upon this distinction I agree that only the implementation would have a finite `int` size and the abstract study retains integers in their infinitely sized mathematical form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you need to know what the $2147483647$-th prime number is, but I'm going to guess it's so you know what data type to store the elements of the array in.

In that case, you only need an approximate value.  The **Prime Number Theorem** tells us that

$$\pi(n)\approx\frac{n}{\log(n)}$$

where $\pi(n)$ is the number of prime numbers less than $n$.  So we are looking for $n$ with $\pi(n)\ge2147483647$ (then there are at least $2147483647$ primes less than $n$, so in particular the first $2147483647$ primes are all smaller than $n$, and can be stored in variables of size $n$).

Let's just ignore the $\approx$ sign and treat it as an equality.  This means we might accidentally get a value that's too small, but let's not worry about that.

So we want

$$\pi(n)=\frac{n}{\log(n)}=2147483647$$

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=solve%20n/log%28n%29=2147483647) gives an answer of $5.303\times 10^{10}$ for $n$.

Now $\log_2(5.03\times 10^{10})\approx 35.5$, so you'd need 36 bits to store that number.

$\log_{10}(5.03\times10^{10})\approx 10.7$, so you'd need $11$ digits to represent the $2147483647$-th prime number in decimal.

Comment: This was exceeding helpful. I hope one day to be better versed in mathematics so I could manage these calculations on my own.

Comment: The approximation of $\pi(x)$ is good asymptotically (prime number theorem) but for any finite number it may be far from the correct value which is 50685770143 for 2147483647 th prime. A better approximation is given by the Riemann prime counting function.

Answer (score 14):

Just so we have an answer:  As Artes has shown, the exact prime is $50685770143$.  This has $11$ decimal digits.  In binary, it is $101111001101000110110111100110011111_2$, which has $36$ bits.