# What is the largest 'sequential' prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

New to this, sorry for bad formatting but:

The largest know prime number is a Mersenne Prime Number, i.e. it is in the form $2^n-1$. Whilst this is big, the last known prime number before this was millions of digits shorter. Take the list $2, 3, 5, 7, 11,\cdots$ in the list $11$ is the largest (prime) number. We know *all* the prime numbers before $11$, though. So, a better way to ask would be as stated below:

What is the largest prime number where we know all the prime numbers before it? Doing some research, I've found that we know the first $50$ million primes or so, but I'm sure with all the computing power we humans have, that cannot be the limit.

Comment: Say what? $ $ $ $

Comment: Sometimes I think it pays to just use some part of the question as the title; in this case that would be, "What is the largest prime number where we know all the prime numbers before it?" That seems a perfectly clear statement of the question and I can't think of a better way to ask it in so many words.

Comment: My guess is that it's much greater than $10^{100}$. Wolfram Alpha takes barely a couple of seconds to tell me that $10^{100} + 267$ is the next prime. My next query gave me the prime $10^{1000} + 453$.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: That would require a somewhat flexible definition of "known". All of the primes below $10^{100}$ cannot possibly be _listed explicitly_ anywhere -- the observable universe contains too little matter to build enough storage media for that.

Comment: [How many prime numbers are known?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272791/how-many-prime-numbers-are-known) is a near-duplicate of this.

Comment: On the other hand, Wolfram Alpha couldn't give me an exact value for $\pi(10^{100})$. I dropped down to $\pi(10^{10})$ to get the answer 455052511. This suggests that with the right programming, you can have your computer make you a list of the first 400 or 500 million primes. It might take up a gigabyte on your hard drive (something I didn't think about until I saw @Henning's comment).

Comment: Upon further reflection, my `NextPrime` queries aren't all that informative. The powers of 10 that I used happened to be in relatively small prime gaps, so even by crude trial and error, it would not take too much time to find the primes I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Henning Yeah, that's the duplicate alright.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks for the duplicate checking, unfortunately I didn't find any of those during my (by your standards, brief) searching.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Wolfram Alpha is a great mathematical engine, though most of the questions you asked are simply stored in a **massive** database ready to be fetched later, the exponent of pi is one of millions of examples.

Comment: @DavidK obviously so. I'm really bad at wording my questions but thank you for the point-out.

Comment: @Cryogenic: I used the advanced technique of skimming through the "Related" links shown to the right of this comment thread, and following the duplicate links from there. :-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see :p. Might use it later lol

Comment: @Cryogenic Fair enough. Though I've just now tried $\pi(10^{10} - 3^8)$ and it seems to have given me the answer just as quickly. The speed of my Internet connection would probably be the only difference between Wolfram Alpha and if I had my own copy of Mathematica at home.